# How to get all factual monetize deals wit ruby driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, factual

I tried to get all deals for a city in the US from the Factual monetize API by the help of the ruby driver

```
query = factual.monetize.filters("place_locality" => "San Francisco")
```

Is there a limit of 20 results? How is it possible to get more deals?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `query.page(1, :per => 100)` as described in point 6 of https://github.com/Factual/factual-ruby-driver#more-read-examples?

Answer (score 0):

## You can chain the query methods, like this:

```
factual.table("places").filters("category" => "Food & Beverage > Restaurants").search("sushi", "sashimi")
.geo("$circle" => {"$center" => [34.06021, -118.41828], "$meters" => 5000})
.sort("name").page(2, :per => 10)
```